# Concatenate factors in R

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a set of factors as follows:

```
str(range)
int[1:2] 4 5
set=collection$words[range]
set
[1] movie X    
Levels: hated I movie the X
print(paste("Talking about",set))

"Talking about movie"  "Talking about X"
```

What I want to achieve is whatever be the number of strings in the collection 'set' should appear 'concatenated' as one string when printing, example here when I run the `print(paste())` command it should print

```
Talking about movie X
```

and this should be dynamic for any number of strings in the `set` collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `code` showed, 'set' is a `vector` of words derived based on the numeric index in 'range'.  To concatenate the elements in 'set', first `paste` it together with `collapse=' '`).

```
paste('Talking about', paste(set, collapse=' '))
#[1] "Talking about movie X"
```

#### data

```
set <- factor(c('movie', 'X'))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun exactly what I was looking for.